# Javascript RegEx trouble in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split a string in Javascript using a Regular Expression. My code is as follows:

```
var status = "This is a test http://yfrog.com/5y6eruj";    
var regexp = /(http:\/\/yfrog\.com(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?)/gi;  
matchParts = status.split(regexp);
alert(matchParts);
```

In Chrome and FF when I alert `matchParts` it is an array containing the text and then the url. In IE however `matchParts` is just the text and the url has vanished!

Either there is an odd bug in IE or my Regular Expression isn't quite right...please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not use "split" for this, because it's buggy: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split

Try

```
var matchParts = regexp.exec(status);
```

instead. You may have to tinker with the regex a bit (I'll try it and update).

**edit** If you add `(.*)` to the beginning of the regular expression, you'll pick up the leading text too.