# Javascript regex cross-browser discrepancy

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

This piece of code brings different results from Firefox to IE8:

```
var text = "[AMOUNT] MILES DEDUCTED IN [CABIN] FOR [ORIGIN]";
var splitArray = text.split(/[\[\]]/);
alert(splitArray.length);
```

In Firefox, the alert gives 7. 
Whereas in IE, it gives 5.

I tried...

[Javascript RegEx trouble in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401914/javascript-regex-trouble-in-internet-explorer)

but it doesn't work.

Any idea please? 
Thanks!

Comment: What does `splitArray` contain exactly in FF and IE? And if you said you "tried" the answer from the other question, did you actually use the script: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split?

Comment: Browsers differ in their behavior with respect to `.split()` on regular expressions. [See this page.](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split)

Comment: @FelixKling Firefox gives empty strings at the beginning and end of the array, representing the square brackets at the start and end of the original string.

Comment: @Pointy: Ah, interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next code does not fully tested, but in quick test it work ok:

To get IE8 and less splitting behavior:

```
var text = "[AMOUNT] MILES DEDUCTED IN [CABIN] FOR [ORIGIN]";
var arr = text.match(/[^\[\]]+/g);
// arr is ["AMOUNT", " MILES DEDUCTED IN ", "CABIN", " FOR ", "ORIGIN"]
```

To get FF splitting behavior:

```
var text = "[AMOUNT] MILES DEDUCTED IN [CABIN] FOR [ORIGIN]";
var arr = text.match(/[^\[\]]+|^(?=[\[\]])|[^\[\]]?(?=[\[\]]$)|[^\[\]]?(?=[\[\]]{2})/g);
// arr is ["", "AMOUNT", " MILES DEDUCTED IN ", "CABIN", " FOR ", "ORIGIN", ""]
```